# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need some help with some script that I've been running for about 18 months, that has suddenly stopped working.

The script takes responses from a google form to fill out a google doc template and save a copy in a folder.

As of Tuesday (6th Jun) the script no longer completes the form. I receive no error messages in my email in box, and the only indication of an error is when I execute the script from the editor when I see this  "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')"

Unfortunately, I do not understand enough about the script to see what has changed and why it has suddenly stopped working. I run similar scripts / processes on other forms, and they  are also giving the same errors.

Here is the script

```
function autofillTPNEW(e) {
const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e.values[0]), 'GMT', 'dd-MMM-yy');
var teacher = e.values[2];
var classdate = e.values[4];
var classno = e.values[5];
var level = e.values[7];
var observer = e.values[8];
var planning = e.values[9];
var summary = e.values[10];
var next = e.values[11];
var glp1 = e.values[12];
var glp2 = e.values[13];
var gld = e.values[14];
var gcm = e.values[15];
var gcfl = e.values[16];
var gec = e.values[17];
var gtl = e.values[18];
var gca = e.values[19];
var gtm = e.values[20];
var grap = e.values[21];
var gscf = e.values[22];
var gfg = e.values[6];

var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("1mxD-f3XZUzXopap_NA30odsjo7D5ski0tHxCpmARsIE");
var templateresponsefolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1IURpTaJ9PnKbV0Wc79NO2FoyciWCOuO4");

var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(teacher +`, `+ classno +', '+classdate, templateresponsefolder);

var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText('{{tpaname}}', teacher);
body.replaceText("{{tpadate}}", classdate);
body.replaceText("{{tpaclass}}", classno);
body.replaceText("{{tpalevel}}", level);
body.replaceText("{{tpaobsv}}", observer);
body.replaceText("{{tpaplanning}}", planning);
body.replaceText("{{tpasummary}}", summary);
body.replaceText("{{tpanext}}", next);
body.replaceText("{{LP1}}", glp1);
body.replaceText("{{LD}}", gld);
body.replaceText("{{CM}}", gcm);
body.replaceText("{{CFL}}", gcfl);
body.replaceText("{{EC}}", gec);
body.replaceText("{{TL}}", gtl);
body.replaceText("{{CA}}", gca);
body.replaceText("{{LP2}}", glp2);
body.replaceText("{{TM}}", gtm);
body.replaceText("{{RAP}}", grap);
body.replaceText("{{SCF}}", gscf);
body.replaceText("{{FG}}", gfg); 
  
doc.saveAndClose()
}
```

I have seen some similar posts and responses, where e.values is changed for e.responses or e.itemresponses, but I'm not sure if they are relevent for my case.

I'm sure there is a very simple answer, as it is a simple process, but I can't see it.

All and any help much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: You cannot execute the script from the editor without supplying the event object so be way is to submit the form and attempt to debug it with Logger.log and possibly console output.

Comment: In the project for the function `autofillTPNEW` check the exectuion log after a form has been filled out.  I'm assuming this is an installed trigger.

Comment: UPDATE - the process is now working again. I didn't change or edit anything, so now I'm even more baffled. Still no email error messages, just 3 days when the docs were not produced. Thankfully, I have the data in the Google sheet to reproduce them. Thanks for the comments.